# How to change browser scroll position from vertical to horizontal

Tags: javascript, scroll

[image: Website section with horizontal scroll]

[Website Link](https://www.ouiwill.com/about/)

Hello Devs,
Please how can I create this horizontal scroll....

Notice it changes from vertical to horizontal when the user gets to that section of the website

I tried using  scrollY position to make that section move with translateX but i failed

Comment: You should update chrome, there is a new feature to manage tabs 

Comment: 1) The scroll bar does not move from vertical to horizontal

Comment: 2) It is made with [GSAP ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/) ------------- [Example](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/bGexQpq)

Comment: 3) Some demos: https://greensock.com/st-demos/